# Error msg: "post https //api.parse.com/1/logout 400 (bad request)" when try to log into Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, parse-platform, bad-request

Every time I tried to log in use the following angular js code, it always returns this error "post https //api.parse.com/1/logout 400 (bad request)". And I checked the session and it looked right, just won't redirect. But if I click the submit again, it will log in and redirect, but on a different session (of course).

Please help. Thanks a lot.

My view (logIn.html) looks like this:

```
<form name="logInForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="logInUsername">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" id="logInUsername"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="logInPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" id="logInPassword"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="logMeIn(user)">Log In</button>
        <a href="#/signUp">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller (logInController.js) looks like this:

```
(function() {

Parse.initialize("applicationId", "key");

    var logInController = function ($scope, $location, $window) {

        $scope.logMeIn = function(form) {

            Parse.User.logIn(form.username, form.password, {
                success: function(user) {
                    $window.alert("Yay, logged in!");
                    var sessionToken = Parse.User.current()._sessionToken;
                    return $location.path("/landing");
                },
                error: function(user, error) {
                    $window.alert("Oh, NO");
                }
            });
        };
    };

    logInController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$window'];

    angular.module('customerApp')
      .controller('logInController', logInController);
}());
```